# Div in bxslider not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

i am trying to use bxslider for my page but unable to get result that is in bottom link
or i am not sure how to call it in my page

```
<ul class="bxslider">
      <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
      <li><img src="/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var slider_array = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // launch bxslider
  $('.bxslider').each(function(i) {
    slider_array[i] = $(this).bxSlider({
      controls: true
    });
  });


  // bind controls on custom controls, and run functions on every slider
  $('.bxslider-controls a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('pull-left')) {
      var obj = $(this).parent().parent().find('.bxslider');
      var index = $('.bxslider').index(obj);
      slider_array[index].goToPrevSlide();


    } else if ($(this).hasClass('pull-right')) {
      var obj = $(this).parent().parent().find('.bxslider');
      var index = $('.bxslider').index(obj);
      slider_array[index].goToNextSlide();
    }

  });

});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpB1l.jpg)

Comment: you need to show your jquery code  that loads `bxslider`

Comment: js code added please check

Comment: *"...unable to get result that is in bottom link "* What result? The image doesn't help at all. 2 questions: 1. What do you expect to happen? 2. What is happening instead?